# Porting some Obj-C code with NSValue and NSDictionary::objectForValue to cocos2d-x

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x

It seems that cocos2d-x has no any build-in analogs for NSValue, so I have some troubles with converting the following method:

```
- (BOOL)isEmpty:(id)target :(CGPoint)position {
    BOOL result = YES;   

    // objectForKey receives "id" parameter, not "const &string" 
    Trail *trail = [_objects objectForKey:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position]];

    if(trail && [trail.target isEqual:target]) {
        result = NO;
    }
    return result;
}
```

cocos2d-x has own implementation for NSDictionary called CCDictionary, with the same logic. So I can store objects in the same way as I do in Objective-C, but what I can't do is to extract objects by their keys, where key has 'id'-like type. CCDictionary can extract values only when key type is std::string or int. And as I've mentioned above, cocos2d-x has no any analog of NSValue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, being `NSDictionary` an Objective-C class, you can only use it from Objective C. This is not strictly related to cocod2d.

What you should do, IMO, is using `std::map` instead of `NSDictionary` to keep your obejcts. Then you would be 100% C++.

Comment: cocos2d-x has own implementation for NSDictionary called CCDictionary, with the same logic. So I can store objects with the same way as in Objective-C, but what I can't do - is extract object by key, where key has 'id'-like type. CCDictionary can extract values only when key type is std::string or int. And I've mentioned above, cocos2d-x has no any analog for container NSValue.

Comment: I see. On the other hand, it seems that CCDictionary will not allow you to `setObject` for but a `string` or `int` key. So, how are you adding you object to the CCDictionary? Not by specifying an `NSValue` key...

Comment: `CCDictionary` is designed for storing another cocos2d-x specific class called `CCObject` (and of course for all classes which extends CCObject): `setObject(cocos2d::CCObject *pObject, const std::string &key);`

Comment: ...so I can put and extract data when I have string or int key value, but.. how can I get string/int key value from CCPoint (CGPoint's cocos2-x adaptation) object without NSValue and it's `valueWithCGPoint` method?

Comment: I think you are bound to create a CCObject derived class to support the conversion CGPoint/String as required. I think it would be so much easier to just use std::map. Or are you using some cocos2d method requiring a CCDictionary?

Comment: I have to use CCDictionary, because it is important component of many cocos2d-x library parts... Thank you anyway, @sergio.

Comment: I see. What you could do, in this case, is converting from CGPoint into string and back yourself: you could use something like "xValue@yValue" so you easily encode and decode.

Comment: I want to know what exactly you wanna do? As far as I understand, I think you want to store position value for some trail or path drawing. Right?